# How to store value into static variable from volley's onResponse()

Tags: android, android-volley, mpandroidchart

See `BarChartPosNegActivity.data_str=jsonArray.toString();`
I get the data from web DB via PHP file and volley
And I store data into `BarChartPosNegActivity.data_str` static variable

When I run the code, at first, `BarChartPosNegActivity.data_str` prints "aa" due to initialized variable `static String data_str="aa";`

And after I push "back" button and I re-enter current activity (barchart screen using MPAndroidChart), `BarChartPosNegActivity.data_str` prints data of table

How can I directly store data of table into `BarChartPosNegActivity.data_str` without "back screen and re-enter the screen"?

```
public class BarChartPosNegActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    // ================================================================================
    ...

    // Create static variable
    static String data_str="aa";

    // ================================================================================
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        // ================================================================================
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // ================================================================================
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bar_chart_pos_neg);

        // ================================================================================
        ... 

        get_refDB_up_down_numerical_table();
        System.out.println(BarChartPosNegActivity.data_str);

        // ================================================================================
        // Create BarDataSet1 object
        BarDataSet barDataSet1=new BarDataSet(dataValues1(),"DataSet 1");

        ...

    }

    // ================================================================================
    void get_refDB_up_down_numerical_table()
    {
        Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response)
            {
                try
                {
                    JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray(response);
                    BarChartPosNegActivity.data_str=jsonArray.toString();
                }
                catch (JSONException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        RefDBNumericRequest loginRequest = new RefDBNumericRequest(responseListener);
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(BarChartPosNegActivity.this);
        queue.add(loginRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move this code:

```
System.out.println(BarChartPosNegActivity.data_str);

// ================================================================================
// Create BarDataSet1 object
BarDataSet barDataSet1=new BarDataSet(dataValues1(),"DataSet 1");
...
```

into the onResponse handler. This function is called when you get the response back from the HTTP call.

Comment: Hi. I think your suggestion can be good if I use "one table loading code" with volley's onResponse. But I should retrieve multiple tables, such as, userTable, referenceDBTable, ... (probably meaning I should call multiple different volley onResponse) So, I'm thinking I should collect all data which is retrieved from database into current activity's static variables as I wrote in the above question

Comment: @YoungMinPark, yes the general idea is that every API call should be handled in its own onResponse. Also, remember that you're making an API call, not a DB query. It's just semantics, but it matters when you're asking for help.

Comment: Even if above suggestion was not exact solution which I expected, I have used that suggestion "with join query" to generate one large table to avoid multiple calls for volley request. And I'm proceeding charting algorithm inside of onResponse. Thanks for the suggestion.